# Unexpected context menu behaviour while using multiple monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, context-menu

[image]

I connect a monitor to my win 8 laptop and use. The larger monitor is set to be my primary display, and laptop is secondary.

Ignore the black color on the image.

You can clearly notice my problem.. it's that the submenu of a context menu item appears in second monitor.

Anyone else have the same problem? Is this a bug? How to report?

Comment: You can report bugs with most Microsoft products on Microsoft Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the software for your NVIDIA graphics card.

Try updating the drivers and the management software with the latest from the NVIDIA website.